# How to change Action Bar and Status Bar color in activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I want to change the color of my **action bar and status bar** programmatically only on one activity, depending it's state, green for go and red for stop. I want to keep the system wide theme of orange and only have the red or green depending on the outcome of whats inside the activity, with an if Statement.
How could it be possible to do that?

Comment: I also need to change the colour of my status bar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if I understand correctly you want to change from java code .. When you call an if try to use this method:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        changeColor(R.color.red);
    }


    public void changeColor(int resourseColor) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), resourseColor));
        }

        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(resourseColor)));

    }

}
```

Comment: What do I call "red"? can I call it as a variable named "#FF0000

Comment: `R.color.red` is defined color name in *`res/values/colors.xml`*. Example: `<color name="red">#770000</color>` @zarrexx

Comment: @MattDeveloper How to do that in lover version than API 21?

Comment: no but red is undefined

Comment: How can i set it within the java rather than xml?

Comment: `changeColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));` causes my activity to crash

Comment: @zarrexx if you want to use class variable with "#FF0000" value. You can use `Color.parseColor(stringVariable);` instead of `ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), resourseColor)` and `getResources().getColor(resourseColor)`.

Comment: Could you show how I could adapt the `changeColor` method to use `changeColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));`

Comment: @zarrexx look there: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4w2kqnaak8149wx/answer_.txt?dl=0

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by defining the custom theme for activity. First you need to create `styles.xml` file in *`res/values/`* path.

## styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/color_primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then in your `AndroidManifest.xml` write:

```
<activity 
       android:name=".MyActivity"
       android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"/>
```

Or in your activity:

```
setTheme(android.R.style.MyCustomTheme);
```

Comment: Needs to be done programmatically within the activity not the XML file

Comment: You can use `setTheme(android.R.style.MyCustomTheme)` method after your `if()` statement. @zarrexx